# vertical align woocommerce product gallery thumbnails

Tags: php, css, wordpress, hook-woocommerce

i want to vertically align woocommerce gallery thumbnails on product page.  there is no exact advice anywhere on internet (except if using storefront theme - and i am unsure which information to edit if use same code).

i am using divi theme.

can anyone help by sharing the code which would work for divi theme, or advise what to edit about the storefront theme code for vertical alignment so is ok for divi, or can someone advise where i can find and change the code for making the galleries into one column?

thanks so much in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895773/how-can-i-make-woocommerce-product-gallery-thumbnail-vertical  this is the code given if it was a shopfront theme

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it adding this code in style.css

```
.woocommerce div.product div.images .flex-control-thumbs li {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```